# navigation drawer вылетает

Tags: java, android

Добрый день!
 Начал изучать java, и сразу возник вопрос. Собрал  `navigation drawer`, создал  меню из шести пунктов на фрагментах. Но вот беда, если находясь в первом пункте меню, войти в навигацию, и выбрать опять первый пункт меню, то  ломается все приложение.
 Вопрос  - как сделать неактивным, это  активное меню.
 Заранее благодарен.

```html
package su.mmm.www.bomj;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import su.mmm.www.bomj.Fragments.FragmentBag;
import su.mmm.www.bomj.Fragments.FragmentHome;
import su.mmm.www.bomj.Fragments.FragmentJob;
import su.mmm.www.bomj.Fragments.FragmentMap;
import su.mmm.www.bomj.Fragments.FragmentMarket;
import su.mmm.www.bomj.Fragments.FragmentStatus;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    FragmentBag fragmentBag = new FragmentBag();
    FragmentHome fragmentHome = new FragmentHome();
    FragmentJob fragmentJob = new FragmentJob();
    FragmentMap fragmentMap = new FragmentMap();
    FragmentMarket fragmentMarket = new FragmentMarket();
    FragmentStatus fragmentStatus = new FragmentStatus();

      @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentTransaction ftrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (id == R.id.bag) {
           ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fragmentBag);
        } else if (id == R.id.home) {
            ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fragmentHome);
        } else if (id == R.id.job) {
            ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fragmentJob);
        } else if (id == R.id.market) {
            ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fragmentMarket);
        } else if (id == R.id.status) {
            ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fragmentStatus);
        } else if (id == R.id.map) {
            ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fragmentMap);
        }
ftrans.commit();
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Без сообщения об ошибке и месте его возникновения мы вам помочб не сможем. Тем паче что и вообще вопрос не очень понятен

Comment: Добавте код, Может вопрос будет понятнее.

Comment: Такое стыдно добавлять)

Answer (score 2):

Можете хранить текущий выбранный id.

Когда при нажатии получили его здесь, 
int id = item.getItemId();
то сравниваете с запомненным. Если это один и тот же, то просто выходите из метода. 
Пример как можно это сделать

```
if (Cur_group_position == (int)menuItem.getItemId()) 
{
      //следующие две строчки опционально по желанию. Может пригодиться
      menuItem.setChecked(true);//отметили элемент чтобы пользователь видел выбранный им раздел
      mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();//закрыли окно
      return true;
}
```

Но вообще мне кажется это скорее костыль. Нужно решать проблему не того чтобы не нажимать два раза на одну кнопку, а понять отчего нажатие этой кнопки вызывает ошибку и соответствующе ее обработать.

Comment: И ради бога, юзайте лучше switch case. Будет выглядеть значительно лучше:)